# I get colors: [object Object] when I try to publish a product, how to solve this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I'm using react-colors and I'm trying to post a product but I'm getting a response with the field `color: [object Object].`

This is my color in product model:
`color: { type: Array },`

This is my newproductpage.jsx where i handle form submit:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const myForm = new FormData();

    myForm.set('name', name);
    myForm.set('price', price);
    myForm.set('description', description);
    myForm.set('quantity', quantity);
    myForm.set('category', category);
    myForm.set('size', size);
    myForm.set('color', colors);

    images.forEach(image => {
      myForm.append('images', image);
    });
    dispatch(createProduct(myForm));
  };
```

This function save color in my colors state:

```
const saveColors = color => {
    const filtered = colors.filter(clr => clr.color !== color.hex);
    setColors([...filtered, { color: color.hex }]);
  };
```

When i `console.log(colors)` im getting:

`Array [ {…} ] ​   0: Object { color: "#fcb900" } ​​ color: "#fcb900"`

And thats okay. When i publish post my all fields are okay, just `colors: [object Object]`

This is my color in form:

```
 <Form.Group className='mb-3'>
            <Form.Label>Product Color</Form.Label>
            {colors.length > 0 && <h1>colors list</h1>}
            {colors.length > 0 &&
              colors.map((color, i) => (
                <div
                  className='p-3 me-2 rounded d-inline-block'
                  key={color.i}
                  style={{ background: color.color }}
                  onClick={() => deleteColor(color)}
                ></div>
              ))}
            <TwitterPicker onChangeComplete={saveColors} />
          </Form.Group>
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, your colors is an array of objects so you should send them with the proper way in FormData.

1. using JSON.stringify and handle the string data in the backend:

```js
myForm.append('color', JSON.stringify(colors));
```

2. Send as an array in FormData:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  myForm.append('colors[]', colors[i]);
}
```

Comment: When i do this i getting something like this color: [ "[{\"color\":\"#f78da7\"},{\"color\":\"#7bdcb5\"}]" ] . in my mongodb "[{"color":"#f78da7"},{"color":"#7bdcb5"}]"

Comment: I am stupid... i just needed to add in my new Product ({color: JSON.parse(color)})